# Obtain URLs from search using rvest

Tags: r, web, screen-scraping, rvest

I am trying to obtain URLs for searches into Western Union website from Nigerian provinces. In particular, I want to search this following [webpage](https://locations.westernunion.com/search/nigeria/) for a vector of provinces, and for each search to keep the corresponding URL to then webscrape each of the obtained links. I know how to do the second step but not the first one. In particular, my code is

```
#install.packages("selectr")
#install.packages("xml2")
library(selectr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(xlsx)
provinces = as.vector(read.xlsx("provinces.xls", 1)[,1])

URL <- "https://locations.westernunion.com/search/nigeria/"
webpage <- read_html(URL)
```

But now I don't know how to proceed to search and store the URL for each of my provinces from the vector mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the `href` attribute which ends with `"Nigeria"` of the `div` tag with class `info`

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

URL <- "https://locations.westernunion.com/search/nigeria/"

URL %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("div.info a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  grep("Nigeria$", ., value = TRUE)

#[1] "/ng/ebonyi/onueke/47908be48d424b6fba108b020c60b517?loc=+Nigeria"      
#[2] "/ng/plateau/plateau/393aa00a34ded9201b3c0c2fd70c02b3?loc=+Nigeria"    
#[3] "/ng/bayelsa/otuoke/046d3ae90f58169a7cc896b96e9ccfac?loc=+Nigeria"     
#[4] "/ng/ogun/abeokuta/fab00c55961bc48312029f13e7b75277?loc=+Nigeria"      
#[5] "/ng/ogun/idi-iroko/63803a3c50d4cb4b44f473cfd8cb96b1?loc=+Nigeria"     
#[6] "/ng/-/akwaibom/4c1dd6c2953a0d396500157d97ddf0ca?loc=+Nigeria"  
#....
```

However, I think this is just a part of URL and you need to add `"https://locations.westernunion.com"` to each extracted part to get exact URL

```
URL %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("div.info a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  grep("Nigeria$", ., value = TRUE) %>%
  paste0("https://locations.westernunion.com", .)

#[1] "https://locations.westernunion.com/ng/ebonyi/onueke/47908be48d424b6fba108b020c60b517?loc=+Nigeria"      
#[2] "https://locations.westernunion.com/ng/plateau/plateau/393aa00a34ded9201b3c0c2fd70c02b3?loc=+Nigeria"    
#[3] "https://locations.westernunion.com/ng/bayelsa/otuoke/046d3ae90f58169a7cc896b96e9ccfac?loc=+Nigeria"     
#[4] "https://locations.westernunion.com/ng/ogun/abeokuta/fab00c55961bc48312029f13e7b75277?loc=+Nigeria"      
#[5] "https://locations.westernunion.com/ng/ogun/idi-iroko/63803a3c50d4cb4b44f473cfd8cb96b1?loc=+Nigeria"     
#[6] "https://locations.westernunion.com/ng/-/akwaibom/4c1dd6c2953a0d396500157d97ddf0ca?loc=+Nigeria" 
#....
```

and now these URL's can be used for step 2 of the process.